# Regexp type for closure compiler

Tags: javascript, regex, types, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

I'm currently adding type annotation to a personnal javascript module, but I'm currently stuck when trying to type function taking a regexp as a parameter, but none of the follwing tries is working :

```
/** @type {function(RegExp)} */
/** @type {function(regex)} */
```

I'm only getting :

```
WARNING - Bad type annotation. Unknown type regexp
```

What type should I use in the declaration? thanks.

Comment: The first annotation `@type {function(RegExp)}` should work. The examples I posted below both checked out okay using the [Closure Compiler Service](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) with verbose warnings.

Comment: sounds like you are missing externs.  How are you running the compiler?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `RegExp` object is annotated for the [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) in the extern [es3.js](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/externs/es3.js). Here is an example function that accepts a `RegExp` object.

```
/**
 * @param {RegExp} regex A regular expression object.
 * @param {string} text Text to match.
 * @return {string} The first match in text.
 */
var firstMatch = function(regex, text) {
  var match = regex.exec(text);
  return match[1];
};

var text = 'Where art thou?';
var regex = new RegExp('^\\W*(\\w+)\\b', 'g');
var firstWord = firstMatch(regex, text);
alert(firstWord); // displays "Where"
```

The same function annotated using **`@type`**:

```
/** @type {function(RegExp, string): string} */
var firstMatch = function(regex, text) {
  var match = regex.exec(text);
  return match[1];
};
```

## Default Externs

The Closure Compiler includes [default externs](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/tree/master/externs) such as es3.js, es5.js, and es6.js.
**These externs files do not normally need to be explicitly specified**, unless the following flag is set:

**[Closure Compiler Application](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app)**: `--use_only_custom_externs=true`

**[Closure Compiler Service UI](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_ui)**: `@exclude_default_externs true`

**[Closure Compiler Service API](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_api)**: `exclude_default_externs=true`

## Additional Externs

There are additional externs available under [contrib/externs](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/tree/master/contrib/externs) that are not included by default. These externs may be specified with the `--externs` flag.

Comment: Thanks, your answer put me on the right tracks, I just need to add a --externs es3.js to get better type checking

Answer (score 0):

There's no separate regexp type in JSDoc according to [GCC's list of types](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#types) and regexp themselves have type "object". You can use `@typedef` to alias "regexp" to "object" if you wish to make your annotations more readable and meaningful. It will also allow to quickly adapt in future if this type is actually added - you will only need to remove or change alias.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this page, but I was hoping it was just undocumented :-/